# How to display count() with rows equal to zero with a single table

Tags: sql, oracle

So basically, let's say I have a table called "sales" listing every sales made from a shop.

To keep it simple we will keep three columns :

```
 SALE_ID    DATE_SALE     VENDOR    

1   101     2019/01/01      Camille 
2   102     2019/01/01      Lucas
3   103     2019/01/02      Rudy   
4   104     2019/01/01      Lucas
5   105     2019/01/01      Delphine
6   106     2019/01/03      Penelope
7   107     2019/01/02      Rudy
8   108     2019/01/03      Delphine
9   109     2019/01/03      Camille   
10  110     2019/01/04      Rudy
11  111     2019/01/02      Camille
12  112     2019/01/04      Penelope
```

I'm Simply trying to sum up each vendor sales for a given period of time. So naturally I try and use a count() function with a "group by" instruction :

```
select vendor, count(vendor)
from sales 
where vendor in ('Camille', 'Lucas', 'Delphine', 'Rudy', 'Penelope', 'Alice')
group by vendor    
order by vendor;
```

The output is as follow :

```
    VENDOR      COUNT(VENDOR)       

1   Camille     3   
2   Delphine    2
3   Lucas       2   
4   Penelope    2
5   Rudy        3
```

As you might have noticed, there's one more name in the query and I require her to appear with 0 in the count column.

I saw many topics with the same subject, but they all relied on several tables and the solution Always implied some kind of outer join. I only have one table and it is the only one I can work with, so unfortunately this solution is not applicable.

Do you good people have any alternative to suggest ?

I greatly thank you for you time

Comment: You should have a table with all the vendors. What's its name and structure?

Answer (score 1):

I would join with `vendors` table like this:

```
select v.vendor, count(s.vendor)
  from vendors v left outer join sales s on (s.vendor = v.vendor)
 where v.vendor in ('Camille', 'Lucas', 'Delphine', 'Rudy', 'Penelope', 'Alice')
 group by v.vendor
 order by v.vendor;
```

Assuming you have a table named `vendors` with all the vendors (including Alice) in there.

Comment: You need to start with `vendors` and `left join` to `sales`... Or you could use a `right join`, but I find those less intuitive...

Answer (score 0):

Given your comment that you cannot have a `vendors` table, here's an alternative approach that basically creates one for you, and then uses an `outer join` to include `Alice`:

```
select t.name, count(s.vendor) as thecount
from (select column_value name 
      from table(sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll('Camille', 'Lucas', ..., 'Alice'))) t
  left join sales s on t.name = s.vendor
group by t.name
```

Note, there are several different ways of creating the fake table.  This uses a built-in procedure that you should have access to.  Alternatively you could be more explicit and define it using `union all`.

- [Condensed Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b3007/1)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you don't have a `VENDOR` table you can use an inline view to generate your vendor names:

```
WITH cteVendors as (SELECT 'Camille' AS VENDOR FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'Lucas' AS VENDOR FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'Delphine' AS VENDOR FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'Rudy' AS VENDOR FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'Penelope' AS VENDOR FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'Alice' AS VENDOR FROM DUAL)
SELECT v.VENDOR, COUNT(s.VENDOR)
  FROM cteVendors v
  LEFT OUTER JOIN SALES s
    ON s.VENDOR = v.VENDOR
  GROUP BY v.VENDOR
  ORDER BY v.VENDOR
```

[dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9e7faaaaca692b482038cb652e0720e9)